# Fiddler - IP Address being captured instead of URL from android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, fiddler, network-traffic, play-billing-library

I've been trying to capture the network traffic using Fiddler populated from the Google Play billing library which is being setup in my application hosted inside the Android emulator.

Every time when i set up a connection to Google Play and initiate a purchase flow, IP address of Google Play is being logged in fiddler instead of exact URL. Please check the screenshot below

[image]

Can you please suggest on how to get the exact URL instead of IP address in URL column in Fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you only see IP addresses is that on your Android device you have enabled **Private DNS** feature.

If this is enabled Android first establishes an encrypted connection to the DNS server and requests the IP address of the domain name the app want to connect to. Then in a second step it establishes the connection through the proxy using the already known IP address instead of the DNS host name.

You can disable it in **Android Settings** -> **Network & internet** -> **Advanced** -> **Private DNS**

Afterwards you should see on CONNECT requests the target domain name (CONNECT requests always only contain just the domain name, never the full url).

If you have properly enabled https interception you may then see the HTTPS URLs afterwards. Note that Google often uses certificate pinning in their apps and libraries. Therefore you may not see any requests if certificate pinning is used by the used Google libraries. In such a case you can try to disable certificate pinning by connecting Frida/Objection to your app and to disable the certificate pinning code of the used Google libraries. Objection contains some modules to do so, but I have never used them on the Google client libraries.

Alternatively on a Magisk rooted device you can install edXposed + trustMeAlready addon which disables certificate checking and pinning for most apps and services on the device.